# Android :Unable to take api response into arraylist

Tags: android

I  am getting the above error following is my code and log cat

```
public class TimeMain {
String name;

public ArrayList<Lecture> getLectures() {
    return lectures;
}

public void setLectures(ArrayList<Lecture> lectures) {
    this.lectures = lectures;
}

ArrayList<Lecture> lectures;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}


class Lecture {
String timming,subject,teachers,rooms;

public String getTimming() {
    return timming;
}

public void setTimming(String timming) {
    this.timming = timming;
}

public String getSubject() {
    return subject;
}

public void setSubject(String subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}

public String getTeachers() {
    return teachers;
}

public void setTeachers(String teachers) {
    this.teachers = teachers;
}

public String getRooms() {
    return rooms;
}

public void setRooms(String rooms) {
    this.rooms = rooms;
}
}
```

This is my api response

```
[
{
    "name": "Monday",
    "lectures": [
        {
            "timing": "9:00-10:00",
            "subject": "TOC",
            "teachers": "MK",
            "rooms": "MK"
        },
        {
            "timing": "10:00-11:00",
            "subject": "TOC",
            "teachers": "MK",
            "rooms": "MK"
        },
        {
            "timing": "11:00-12:00",
            "subject": "JAVA",
            "teachers": "SSJ",
            "rooms": "SSJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:00-12:30",
            "subject": "break",
            "teachers": null,
            "rooms": null
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:30-1:30",
            "subject": "CG",
            "teachers": "VJ",
            "rooms": "VJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "1:30-2:30",
            "subject": "CG",
            "teachers": "VJ",
            "rooms": "VJ"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Tuesday",
    "lectures": [
        {
            "timing": "9:00-10:00",
            "subject": "DCN",
            "teachers": "VJ",
            "rooms": "VJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "10:00-11:00",
            "subject": "C#",
            "teachers": "US",
            "rooms": "US"
        },
        {
            "timing": "11:00-12:00",
            "subject": "JAVA",
            "teachers": "SSJ",
            "rooms": "SSJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:00-12:30",
            "subject": "break",
            "teachers": null,
            "rooms": null
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:30-1:30",
            "subject": "TOC",
            "teachers": "MK",
            "rooms": "MK"
        },
        {
            "timing": "1:30-2:30",
            "subject": "TOC",
            "teachers": "MK",
            "rooms": "MK"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Wednesday",
    "lectures": [
        {
            "timing": "9:00-10:00",
            "subject": "C#",
            "teachers": "US",
            "rooms": "US"
        },
        {
            "timing": "10:00-11:00",
            "subject": "DCN",
            "teachers": "VJ",
            "rooms": "VJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "11:00-12:00",
            "subject": "CG",
            "teachers": "VJ",
            "rooms": "VJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:00-12:30",
            "subject": "break",
            "teachers": null,
            "rooms": null
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:30-1:30",
            "subject": "TOC",
            "teachers": "MK",
            "rooms": "MK"
        },
        {
            "timing": "1:30-2:30",
            "subject": "JAVA",
            "teachers": "SSJ",
            "rooms": "SSJ"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Thursday",
    "lectures": [
        {
            "timing": "9:00-10:00",
            "subject": "TOC",
            "teachers": "MK",
            "rooms": "MK"
        },
        {
            "timing": "10:00-11:00",
            "subject": "TOC",
            "teachers": "MK",
            "rooms": "MK"
        },
        {
            "timing": "11:00-12:00",
            "subject": "JAVA",
            "teachers": "SSJ",
            "rooms": "SSJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:00-12:30",
            "subject": "break",
            "teachers": null,
            "rooms": null
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:30-1:30",
            "subject": "CG",
            "teachers": "VJ",
            "rooms": "VJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "1:30-2:30",
            "subject": "CG",
            "teachers": "VJ",
            "rooms": "VJ"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Friday",
    "lectures": [
        {
            "timing": "9:00-10:00",
            "subject": "DCN",
            "teachers": "VJ",
            "rooms": "VJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "10:00-11:00",
            "subject": "C#",
            "teachers": "US",
            "rooms": "US"
        },
        {
            "timing": "11:00-12:00",
            "subject": "JAVA",
            "teachers": "SSJ",
            "rooms": "SSJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:00-12:30",
            "subject": "break",
            "teachers": null,
            "rooms": null
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:30-1:30",
            "subject": "TOC",
            "teachers": "MK",
            "rooms": "MK"
        },
        {
            "timing": "1:30-2:30",
            "subject": "TOC",
            "teachers": "MK",
            "rooms": "MK"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Saturday",
    "lectures": [
        {
            "timing": "9:00-10:00",
            "subject": "C#",
            "teachers": "US",
            "rooms": "US"
        },
        {
            "timing": "10:00-11:00",
            "subject": "DCN",
            "teachers": "VJ",
            "rooms": "VJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "11:00-12:00",
            "subject": "CG",
            "teachers": "VJ",
            "rooms": "VJ"
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:00-12:30",
            "subject": "break",
            "teachers": null,
            "rooms": null
        },
        {
            "timing": "12:30-1:30",
            "subject": "TOC",
            "teachers": "MK",
            "rooms": "MK"
        },
        {
            "timing": "1:30-2:30",
            "subject": "JAVA",
            "teachers": "SSJ",
            "rooms": "SSJ"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Sunday",
    "lectures": [
        {
            "timing": "12:00-12:30",
            "subject": "break",
            "teachers": null,
            "rooms": null
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Log Cat

11-11 18:06:39.849 5858-5858/com.matrixdev.bvicam.bvicam W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

I want to take above response into array list this code i'm using

```
TimeResponse timeResponse = (TimeResponse) responseObj;
        nameList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (TimeMain timeMain : timeResponse.getTimeMains()) {
            nameList.add(timeMain.getName());
        }
```

TimeResponse Class

```
public class TimeResponse {
ArrayList<TimeMain> timeMains;

public ArrayList<TimeMain> getTimeMains() {
    return timeMains;
}

public void setTimeMains(ArrayList<TimeMain> timeMains) {
    this.timeMains = timeMains;
}
}
```

Comment: could you please precise at what line number you are getting the error?

Comment: make one of those [MCVE]s please

Comment: what library are you using for the api call and gson converter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<TimeMain> timeList = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<TimeMain>>(){}.getTypeToken());
```

should do the job